# Unable to find JavaFX prespective in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Just installed efxeclipse, and following this tutorial (http://download.java.net/general/javafx/eclipse/tutorial.html), yet am unable to find a JavaFX perspective available for my project. The JavaFX SDK shows under the root project within eclipses package explorer, yet I'm unable to find anything relating to java perspective wise other then the usual defaults. Any way to get the perspective up and running at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial is for the 1.x plugin. e(fx)clipse does not have any special perspective because you develop JavaFX2 apps with a combination of:

- Java
- FXML
- CSS

You find tutorials at http://www.efxclipse.org e.g. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1